# Numerical code Friedmann equations

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, computational-physics

I have to write a numerical code to solve the ‘Ω-form’ of the Friedmann equation:

`H(t)^2/H_0^2 =  Ωmat/a^3 + Ωrad/a^4 + Ωk/a^2 + Ωx/a^3(1+w)`

`H(t)=å/a`

where {H0,Ωmat,Ωrad,Ωk,Ωx,w} are constant parameters and a = a(t)/a0 is the normalised scale factor. The numerical integration should be done in terms of a suitable dimensionless time t and should be combined with ‘big-bang’ initial conditions {a(0) = 0, å(0) > 0}. A solution a(t ) represents a ‘cosmological model’. The modern canonical values of the cosmological parameters are:

`Ωmat ≈ 0.3, Ωrad ≈ 0, Ωx = ΩΛ ≈ 0.7, w=−1`

I have to solve the following equations. The first sub-question I already solved, but I don't know how to solve the rest of the questions. Every suggestion is welcome!

- Reproduce and plot the three matter-dominated models (k = {0,±1} and
  Ωrad = Ωx = 0).
- Repeat previous calculation with dark energy added (assume canonical Ωx,w).
- Plot dark energy-dominated models for w = {−1/2,−1,−3/2,−2} (assume canonical
  Ω-parameters).
- Is it possible for a k = +1 model to reach a “big-crunch” in the presence of dark energy? (assume canonical Ωrad, Ωx, w).
- Plot the universe’s age t0 as a function of Ωx for w = {−1/2, −1, −3/2, −2} (assume canonical Ωrad).
- Produce a contour plot of t0 in the Ωx-Ωmat plane (assume canonical Ωrad,w).

Comment: Note we use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as the site standard for mathematical expressions.

Comment: Please cite a reference showing the source of your first equation. The Friedmann equation with  four ΩsI am familiar with familiar is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation . It has  the constant ΩLambda (with no power of a and no w) instead  of Ωx/a^3(1+w).